# How to see which countries the app is allowed?

Tags: google-play-store

I am trying to find where I can install Epokrates Plus app. In Finland, it is not allowed. 
Having my devices, I see in all:

> This app is incompatible with all of your devices.

I tried to send email to the developers but I could not, since Email page just kept loading, and did not let me pass through. Either they are geoblocking or having server downtime.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to see that, as the developer specifically set the filter. However there are still ways to bypass that: Using a VPN or manually downloading the .apk file via online downloading services e.g apkleecher or evozi

Answer (score 1):

- [Sensor Tower](https://sensortower.com/ios/US/epocrates/app/epocrates/281935788/overview?countries=US&countries=CA&countries=AU&countries=CN&category=6020&chart_type=grossing&device=iphone&selected_tab=reviews&date=2018-12-10) overview says USA, Canada, Brazil form 90% of user base remaining being others.
- [Sensor Tower Reviews](https://sensortower.com/ios/US/epocrates/app/epocrates/281935788/review-history?selected_tab=reviews) shows Mexico and Saudi Arabia.

That makes it 6 countries, including India (I see it on Play Store). You could write to them and check for a full list.

**Edit:** I mailed them using Play Store support mail, linking this question and they reverted very promptly. Non availability in some countries is because of GPDR issues. Details pasted in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86904/information-for-leo).